# Best practice to pass a Domain Class between Grails (Groovy) and Java classes?

Tags: java, grails, groovy

I have a Grails service that calls a utility class written in Java. The Java utility class would need to use and manipulate the Domain Classes written in Grails, which are passed into it. Also eventually, the output needs to be a Domain Class in Grails and not a java object.

So basically:
Grails Domain Class input -> manipulated by Java utility class -> Grails Domain Class output to Grails Service and forward to Controller.

What would be the best practice to handle the above? Should I write identical value objects in Java? I guess I cannot manipulate the Grails Domain Classes directly within the Java class?

Comment: Not enough details to be sure, but you should be able to manipulate the Grails domain cases directly within the Java class... What problems are you having?

Comment: I realized this myself a minute ago :) yes, I can actually manipulate the domain class directly in java, not just in groovy...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090710/how-to-use-existing-java-class-from-grails/ : answered it here for anyone who hits this issue with the later grails 2.2+

Answer (score 2):

You can send it to Java classes directly.

One thing to note is that you should be aware of your objects detaching out of the current Hibernate session. If it's the case, you may require to attach it back (using `merge()` for example) to another Hibernate session before further proceed.